# without alert message how to display the error message in below text filed in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

How to display the error message in below text field, below shown script and form without alert message?

**script**

```
success: function (data)
                                {
                                    scrollDown();

                                    var message = $("#messagee").val();

                                      if(message == "" || message == null){ 
                                         alert("enter a message");
                                       }
                                    else {
                                        $('#chat_log').append('<div class="row msg_container base_receive"><div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12"><div class="messages msg_receive"><p><a>' + message + '</a></p></div></div></div>');
                                        $('#messagee').val('');
                                    }
                                },
```

**form**

```
<form class="form-horizontal msg_fixed_bottom send_message_form" id="data_form" method="POST" role="form" action="#" onsubmit="return validation();"> 
    <div class="panel-footer" id="myForm" > 
        <div class="input-group submit_group"> 
            <input id="messagee" name="messagee" type="text" class="form-control input-sm chat_input" placeholder="Write your message here..." value="<?php echo set_value('messagee'); ?>" /> 


            <span class="input-group-btn"> 
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="submit" name="submit">Send</button> 
            </span> 
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a hidden div after the input and show it only if you have errors.

html :

```
<div class="panel-footer" id="myForm" > 



    <div class="input-group submit_group"> 
        <input id="messagee" name="messagee" type="text" class="form-control input-sm chat_input" placeholder="Write your message here..." value="<?php echo set_value('messagee'); ?>" /> 

       <div id="errors" style="display:none;"></div>



        <span class="input-group-btn"> 
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="submit" name="submit">Send</button> 
        </span> 
    </div>
```

js :

```
    success: function (data)
                            {
                                scrollDown();

                                var message = $("#messagee").val();

                                  if(message == "" || message == null){ 

                                      $("#errors").html("enter a message");
                                      $("#errors").fadeIn();
                                   }
                                else {
                                    $('#chat_log').append('<div class="row msg_container base_receive"><div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12"><div class="messages msg_receive"><p><a>' + message + '</a></p></div></div></div>');
                                    $('#messagee').val('');
                                }
                            },
```

don't forget to hide and empty the div at the beginning of your validation() function (Before the **Ajax call**):

```
function validation() {

   $("#errors").fadeOut();
   $("#errors").html("");

   $.ajax({ 

   ... 

   })

}
```

Comment: after display error  message,again enter the values in text field error message will be hide and space should not allowed@FAROUK BLALOU

Comment: You need to init(hide errors before your ajax call (old message will be hidden but if you have any new error message it will be shown again))

Comment: i am not getting what you are saying please edit the code @FAROUK BLALOU

Comment: I don't have your full validation function.... just try it without  $("#errors").fadeOut();
 $("#errors").html(""); and you will get it.

Comment: it is working fine i have one more issues backspace should not be allow @FAROUK BLALOU

Comment: Good ... don't forgot to valid my answer and give me a +1,  and for backspace i don't how but  i will try to find you a solution

Comment: Try to post your backSpace issue in a new Question !!

Answer (score 0):

form

```
<form class="form-horizontal msg_fixed_bottom send_message_form" id="data_form" method="POST" role="form" action="#" onsubmit="return validation();"> 
    <div class="panel-footer" id="myForm" > 
        <div class="input-group submit_group"> 
            <input id="messagee" name="messagee" type="text" class="form-control input-sm chat_input" placeholder="Write your message here..." value="<?php echo set_value('messagee'); ?>" /> 
 <span id='error_msg' class="yourcssclass"></span>

            <span class="input-group-btn"> 
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="submit" name="submit">Send</button> 
            </span> 
        </div>
```

js

```
success: function (data)
                                {
                                    scrollDown();

                                    var message = $("#messagee").val();

                                      if(message == "" || message == null){ 
                                         document.getElementById('error_msg').innerHTML='enter a message';
                                       }
                                    else {
                                        $('#chat_log').append('<div class="row msg_container base_receive"><div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12"><div class="messages msg_receive"><p><a>' + message + '</a></p></div></div></div>');
                                        $('#messagee').val('');
                                    }
                                },
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line with this:

```
<input type="text" name="uname"  value="<?php echo set_value('uname'); ?>" /><div id="infoMessage"><?php echo form_error('uname'); ?></div></br>
```

And change the variables names so they match with your variables names.
Read the [CI documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#showing-errors-individually) for more informations.